# Postfix smtp relay can send emails but not relay other hosts

Tags: postfix, smtp, centos7, stunnel, smtps

Use Case: We have several Eaton PDU/PSUs that don't support SSL/TLS authentication. I was tasked with building a SMTP relay server that can take the basic SMTP/25 emails and forward them to our email provider via SSL.

Note: The relay host makes the smtps connectione on 465 using stunnel.

I am at a point where my SMTP Postfix Relay Server is able to send mail successfully via our email provider, alimail. But I cannot get it to relay emails from other hosts on our network.

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
smtpd_banner = mail01v-la ESMTP
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.96.80.0/24
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:5000
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_use_tls = no
smtp_generic_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/generic
```

**/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd**

```
[127.0.0.1]:5000 notify@domain.com:notifypwd
```

**/etc/postfix/generic**

```
/^root@(.*)$/ notify@domain.com
```

**/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf**

```
client = yes
foreground = no

[smtps]
accept = 5000
connect = smtp.mxhichina.com:smtps
```

**SMTP Telnet to Provider**

```
[root@mail01v-la ~]# telnet smtp.mxhichina.com smtp
Trying 205.204.101.152...
Connected to smtp.mxhichina.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.aliyun-inc.com MX AliMail Server
ehlo google.come
250-smtp.aliyun-inc.com
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN XALIOAUTH
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XALIOAUTH
250-PIPELINING
250 DSN
```

**Checking Stunnel Connection**

```
[root@mail01v-la ~]# telnet 127.0.0.1 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.aliyun-inc.com MX AliMail Server
```

**Sending an Email from the Relay Server**

```
echo "Stack Body" | mail -s "Test Subject for Stack" user@domain.com
```

**Results**

```
Feb 14 18:30:29 mail01v-la postfix/pickup[4812]: 3194940DE2: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 14 18:30:29 mail01v-la postfix/cleanup[4865]: 3194940DE2: message-id=<20200215023029.3194940DE2@mail01v-la.domain.com>
Feb 14 18:30:29 mail01v-la postfix/qmgr[2606]: 3194940DE2: from=<root@mail01v-la.domain.com>, size=481, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 14 18:30:30 mail01v-la postfix/smtp[4867]: 3194940DE2: to=<user@domain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:5000, delay=1.3, delays=0.01/0.01/0.85/0.46, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Data Ok: queued as freedom)
Feb 14 18:30:30 mail01v-la postfix/qmgr[2606]: 3194940DE2: removed
```

[Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekFnX.png)

### Testing with other hosts

**Random CentOS Server**

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf

relayhost = [10.96.80.126]:5000
```

**Result**

```
Feb 14 18:06:52 test01v-la postfix/pickup[1247]: BB87C305A42F: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 14 18:06:52 test01v-la postfix/cleanup[1387]: BB87C305A42F: message-id=<20200215020652.BB87C305A42F@test01v-la.domain.com>
Feb 14 18:06:52 test01v-la postfix/qmgr[1248]: BB87C305A42F: from=<root@test01v-la.domain.com>, size=477, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 14 18:06:53 test01v-la postfix/smtp[1389]: BB87C305A42F: to=<notify@domain.com>, relay=10.96.80.126[10.96.80.126]:5000, delay=0.78, delays=0.01/0.01/0.61/0.15, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host 10.96.80.126[10.96.80.126] said: 553 authentication is required (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

**Eaton PSU**

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwgYz.png)
[creds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fg7d.png)

**Eaton Result**

```
email[17131]: message error -110 in function smtp_start_session test - (Connection timed out) retrying smtp_start_session test email[17131]: Failed to connect to SMTP server 10.96.80.126:5000 with username notify@domain.com
```

### __

This is my first time doing a setup like this. Theres likely a lot of holes in my knowledge that are causing me grief.

1. In a proper setup, do you even need to re-type credentials for any hosts that want to use the relay server? For example, in the eaton smtp config, should it be the creds of the email used in the sasl file? Or a system account permitted for forwarding with postfix? Or an account name defined in the postfix/generic file? A bit lost.
2. Is stunnel even the proper way I should be connecting via ssl/tls? I see starttls available in the telnet prompt for smtp.mxhichina.com.

Honestly, I think I'm overcomplicating this or am missing something obvious. If anyone has a better setup to accomodate my use case, it be greatly appreciated as well.

---

### Switching SSL connection from Stunnel to Postfix only

**Results**

```
Feb 20 11:27:22 mail01v-la postfix/qmgr[1537]: 6B38AE5EE: from=<root@mail01v-la.domain.com>, size=479, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 20 11:27:22 mail01v-la postfix/smtp[1558]: CLIENT wrappermode (port smtps/465) is unimplemented
Feb 20 11:27:22 mail01v-la postfix/smtp[1558]: instead, send to (port submission/587) with STARTTLS
Feb 20 11:27:40 mail01v-la postfix/smtp[1558]: 6B38AE5EE: to=<user@domain.com>, relay=smtp.mxhichina.com[205.204.101.152]:465, delay=613, delays=595/0.02/19/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with smtp.mxhichina.com[205.204.101.152] while receiving the initial server greeting)
Feb 20 11:32:22 mail01v-la postfix/qmgr[1537]: A3F736B2: from=<root@mail01v-la.domain.com>, size=477, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

**main.cf**

```
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.96.80.0/24
relayhost = [smtp.mxhichina.com]:465
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_enforce_tls = yes
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes

soft_bounce = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
```

**/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd**

```
smtp.mxhichina.com notify@domain.com:notifypwd
```

Comment: Tutorials I was following for the setup.

http://archive.eglug.org/book/export/html/1923

http://blog.tremily.us/posts/Postfix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. My original setup was correct except for the port I was trying to connect to from the other clients, which should've been 25, instead of 5000.

EX. In Random CentOS Server:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf

relayhost = [10.96.80.126]:25
```

The reason the Eaton wasn't working was because the network wasn't defined in mynetworks in /etc/postfix/main.cf and because of a routing issue to my OOB network.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.96.80.1/24
```

Looks incorrect - you have specified a single host (not sure how it interprets the associated network.) Try changing the second entry  to 10.96.80.**0**/24

Comment: Thanks, good catch. Definitely need for me to connect from any hosts in that subnet. Unfortunately, still having the same issue. Do you think this looks to be an auth issue with my own smtp server, or the the provider one I'm relaying too?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

are used when postfix acts as a SMTP client, not a server and enables authentication of the postfix itself to the remote server. More details in http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html.

I think you should be enabling

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

and looking at **"Enabling SASL authentication and authorization in the Postfix SMTP server"** section of the abovementioned readme.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using an old Postfix version, you don't need to configure `stunnel` to talk to your e-mail provider using SSL/SMTPS. Postfix >= 3.0 can do so directly by setting the following parameters in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
relayhost = [smtp.mxhichina.com]:465
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_enforce_tls = yes
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes

# Optional, but recommended to prevent mail loss
soft_bounce = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
```

Then, in your `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`, have the following entry defined:

```
smtp.mxhichina.com notify@domain.com:notifypwd
```

Once you change `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` file, make sure that the command line `postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` has been run. In addition, run the command line `postmap -q smtp.mxhichina.com hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` to ensure that authentication credentials have been stored correctly.

Reference: http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_smtps

---

Regarding Eaton PSUs and the other CentOS server in your network, I believe that you just have to set the address of your relay server and the port `25/tcp` as the SMTP server/relayhost:

```
relayhost = [10.96.80.126]:25
```

By doing so, Postfix server will receive e-mail messages using plain and unauthenticated SMTP connections, store them in its own e-mail queue and, then, forward messages to your provider using SSL/SMTPS connections and proper credentials.

Comment: I get the same result from before I started using Stunnel, wherein it states STARTTLS is unimplemented and recommended I use 585 instead. The documentation for that smtp server from my provider however, states to use 465. Results added in edit.

Comment: Trying to change the port to 587, I get "connection timeout"

Trying smtps, I get the same as the 465 result.

Comment: Oh, right... I overlooked the information stating that client-side SMTPS in Postfix requires at least version 3.0 to work ( http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_wrappermode ). That is why you are getting the message `CLIENT wrappermode (port smtps/465) is unimplemented` in your logs. Therefore, STUNNEL is required. I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: Have you tried to configure the PSU to use `10.96.80.126:25` as SMTP server? If so, please could you also provide logs from the Postfix's receiving side (`postfix/smtpd`)?

Comment: Thank you.. that was part of the issue. I was trying to use port 5000.